# Am I required to use django data migrations?

Tags: django, database, django-migrations

I migrated a database that was manipulated via SQL to use Django's migration module: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/.

Initially I thought of using migrations only for changes in the model such as changes in columns or new tables, performing deletes, inserts and updates through SQL, as they are constant and writing a migration for each case would be a little impractical.

Could using the migration module without using data migrations cause me some kind of problem or inconsistency in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You can think about data migration if you made a change that required also a manual fix on the data.

Maybe you decided to normalize something in the database, e.g. to split a name column to the first name and the last name. If you have only one instance of the application with one database and you are the only developer then you will also not write a data migration, but if you want to change it on a live production site with 24 x 7 hours traffic or you cooperate with other developers then you probably prepare a data migration for their databases or you will thoroughly test the migration on a copy of live data that the update will work on the production site correctly without issues and with minimal shutdown. If you don't write a data migration and you had no problem immediately then it is OK and will be not worse then a possible ill-conceived data migration.